# How can I include a Sibling Project in my Gradle Project?

Tags: java, gradle, package, multi-project

I have two Gradle projects with the following directory structure:

```
/baseDir
  /first
  /first/build.gradle
  /second 
  /second/build.gradle
```

Both `first`and `second`are on the same hierarchy. From the [Gradle User](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) Guide I found only a way to include sub projects. This is not the case here.

**How can I include sibling Project second in project first?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use a `settings.gradle` with the following content:

```
 includeFlat "second"
```

Comment: Can you specify where the settings.gradle goes?

Comment: The settings.gradle goes in your root project directory. What would be `baseDir` above.

Comment: Thanks man, I have spent my entire day scratching my head to get it to work. It really helped.